# Trying to understand the logic of fork function return value

Tags: c++, linux, operating-system

Consider this simple program:

```
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    cout << "first pid: " << getpid() << endl;
    int a = fork();
    int b = fork();
    cout << a << " " << b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

So I am running this over and over, and trying to understand what is the pattern that is occuring in every run. I simply do not understand what is happening in terms of the numbers. I originally print the pid before the forks, and then I do not see that pid again, as if it was changed or something. I add 2 different outputs for reference:

```
first pid: 64538
64541 64542
64541 0
0 64543
0 0

first pid: 64625
64628 64629
0 64630
0 0
64628 0
```

What I do understand is that there are now 4 processes alive, since the first fork results with 2 processes and the second fork forks them into 4 proccesses altogether.
What I do not understand is the logic of the IDs printed to the console.

Comment: Since child processes are not synced they print in random order.

Comment: IDs are assigned by the OS due to its own intrinsic "logic". An ID has to be granted (by OS) to be unique, but nothing else (accept that there should be a special No-PID value).

Comment: 64541 in the first output and 64628  in the second appear two times. PIDs on a unix system are usally assigned in ascendig order.

Comment: The important thing to remember is that `fork` is the only function that will return *twice*: Once in the parent and once in the child. In the child process `fork` return `0`. And since there is no synchronization between your processes, one may run to finish before another comes to the second `fork` call, which means that process id's can be reused.

Comment: There is a pattern though, In every run there is one process that prints 2 numbers that are not 0, and the rest print 1 or 2 zeros. What is the explanation for that?

Comment: 0 is returned in child processes.

Comment: I understand, so what exactly happens in the proccess that has no 0 in its print? It has no childs? Sorry I am a little slow on this, I guess I just miss something basic in the way I should think about it

Comment: 0 0 is printed by the child process of second fork() which was child of first fork(). !0 !0 is printed by the parent process of second fork() which was parent in the first fork()...

Comment: @Scheff this is exactly the piece of information I needed to completely understand this. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added comments to the OP to describe what happens:

```
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    cout << "first pid: " << getpid() << endl;
    int a = fork();
    // from here two processes run:
    // in parent a is PID of child
    // in child a is 0
    int b = fork();
    // from here four processes run:
    // a is for parent and child identical 0 or PID
    // in parents b is PID of child
    // in children b is 0
    // Thus, the following shows all 4 combinations of 0 and not 0.
    cout << a << " " << b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a table of what is going on:

```
gen_0     | gen_1         | gen_2_0       | gen_2_1
          |               |               |
==[ before first fork ]==================================
started   |               |               |
pid = 123 |               |               |
          |               |               |
--[ after first fork ]===================================
          | started       |               |
          | pid = 1111    |               |
          | parent: gen_0 |               |
a = 1111  | a = 0         |               |
          |               |               |
--[ after second fork ]==================================
          |               | started       | started
          |               | pid = 2222    | pid = 3333
          |               | parent: gen_0 | parent: gen_1
a = 1111  | a = 0         | a = 1111      | a = 0
b = 2222  | b = 3333      | b = 0         | b = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'logic' is that zero means you're the child of the `fork()`, -1 means an error, and *any* positive number is the PID of the child and that you are the parent.

There is no specified 'logic' as to how PIDs get allocated. Don't look for any.

Comment: There is a pattern though, In every run there is one process that prints 2 numbers that are not 0, and the rest print 1 or 2 zeros. What is the explanation for that?